# Delete opening and closing quotes (or brackets,braces,etc) at once

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

The opening and closing quotes (or brackets, braces etc) are highlighted in PyCharm(and other editors). So this means it can identify the pair.

Now, is there a way to delete both the quotes at once (or brackets, braces etc) when either of the opening or closing quotes are deleted, Since it identifies the pair?

For eg. I want this in one keyboard action (by both cases either deleting the opening or closing square bracket):
From this: `[[a for a in l1 if a!=0]]`
To this: `[a for a in l1 if a!=0]`

I googled and searched on SO but couldn't find it.

Comment: Are you only looking for PyCharm or any other editor?

Comment: PyCharm will do. Welcome for other editors also.

Comment: @frlan: Come to think of it, it's an interesting option. Do you know any editor that does this, then?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=286494, you can get some idea from this

Comment: @akashkarothiya Didn't help much. I don't have eclipse right now so coudn't test. Not working in PyCharm.

Comment: try to delete first quote `"`, it will automatically delete its last (companion) quote. in eclipse its working, please check for Pycharm, I hope it will work there also

Comment: Nop. It doesn't works in PyCharm. Both the quotes will delete only when there is nothing inside the quotes and you delete the opening quote from inside using a backspace.

Comment: Geany is able to do this too. (There is a plugin adding a bunch of features like this)

Comment: Updated my question. Can you confirm if that's possible in geany? And if it is then which plugin and how to do it?

Comment: @akashkarothiya can you do that in eclipse? See the updated question.

Comment: Nopes :( @MohammadYusufGhazi

Comment: tpope's vim-surround plugin does this (for vim that is, not pycharm) ds" ds) ds] ds' etc while cursor is on the surrounding characters or between them

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: Yes. Plugin Auto-Close and activate deleting pairing braces with shift+backspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with macros.

1. Place the cursor after the closing bracket:

```py
  [[a for a in l1 if a!=0]]
#                          ^ - place cursor here
```

2. Go to **Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording**

Press the following:

3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>  - "Move Caret to Matching brace" action.

```py
  [[a for a in l1 if a!=0]]
#^ - it will jump here
```

4. <kbd>Del</kbd> or select action "Delete to Word End".

```py
  [a for a in l1 if a!=0]]
#^ - the first bracket was deleted
```

5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>  - "Last Edit Location" (assuming you edited there).

```py
  [a for a in l1 if a!=0]]
#                         ^ - will jump here
```

6. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or "Delete to Word Start"

```py
  [a for a in l1 if a!=0]
#                        ^ - deleted the paired closing bracket
```

Now need to stop macro recording.

7. Go to **Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording**
8. Give a name to your macros
9. Optionally, assign shortcut to it.

---

Links:
[Macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) documentation.
[Source code navigation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html) documentation.
Other [suggestion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206342409-Deleting-opposite-bracket) to use **Code|Unwrap/Remove**. It will not work in some cases. For example, if you have incorrect code, the IDE cannot wrap it.

Comment: Waiting for answer how to add current position to Recent Locations. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/14498377055634-Manually-add-current-position-to-Recent-Locations

Answer (score 0):

I know of 2 quick ways, but none of them is quick enough.

1: Using the AceJump addon, you just jump to one parens, hit delete, then jump to the other one, and hit delete... Naturally this has the disadvantage that parentheses in a situation like this: ([{(([]))}) would be harder to jump to.

2: There is a command called "Move caret to matching brace". Then, using either AceJump to jump directly to your first brace (or just navigating to it in any way), you activate the function "Move caret to matching brace 2 times". After moving the caret 2 times, you can delete the first matching parens, and then use the action to navigate back ("Back"), and then delete your second brace.

3: Solution 2 does not work for quotes. For them, instead of executing the action "Move to matching brace" you can use the incremental selection, and jump to the most convenient of the 2 quote signs... This however doesn't allow you to navigate back to the previous(or next) quote and delete that one. Therefore for quotes, I have no solution, but this "incremental selection" can work in a few situations (when one of the quotes is at the beginning or the end of a line)

Comment: I cannot edit the post. Here is a link to AceJump plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086-acejump